# For the following functions, the domain and codomain is {a,b,c,d} which ones are one to one and which are onto? Give reasons for each

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

For the following functions, the domain and codomain is {a,b,c,d} which ones are one to one and which are onto? Give reasons for each.

a) f(a) = b, f(b) = a , f(c) = c, f(d) = d

b) f(a) = b, f(b) = b, f(c) = d, f(d) = c

c) f(a) = d, f(b) = b, f(c) = c, f(d) = d

Comment: Do you have any thoughts yourself?

Comment: @Henry I think f(a) = b is a one to one function. I also think f(b) = a is a one to one function. I dont think f(c) = c or f(d) = d are one to one functions.. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a [one-to-one function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)?  For example the answer to a) $f(a) = b, f(b) = a , f(c) = c, f(d) = d$ is "yes it is one-to-one", or "no it is not one-to-one", not "bits of it are and bits not"

Comment: I think you need to do a lot more work on the concept of function and then come back to this question.  From your comment, it seems as if you are taking (a) to be four separate functions.  It's not, it's just one function.

Comment: Whoops. I'm an idiot @Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f$ is *one-to-one* if and only if $f(a) = f(b)$ implies $a = b$. That is, the function always maps distinct values to distinct values.

A function $f$ is *onto* if and only if for every $b$ in the codomain, there exists an $a$ such that $f(a) = b$. In other words, the function hits every element in its codomain.

**a)** There is no element in the codomain that is hit by two different elements in the domain, and all elements in the codomain are hit. So $f$ is both one-to-one and onto.

**b)** We see that $f(a) = b$ and $f(b) = b$, so $f$ maps two distinct elements to the same element $b$, and it is therefore *not* one-to-one. We also see that $a$ is not hit, so it is also *not* onto.

**c)** Very similar to **b)**, so I'll leave this one to you!